# Getting the day from a timestamp returns the month

Tags: php, date

I have the following datetime:

```
09/05/2016 09:12 (9 May 2016)
```

I want to get the day from it so I do

```
date('d', strtotime($date))
```

but this returns 05, which is the month.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because {J{ thinks it is an American date format.

Try changing the slashes `(/)` to dashes `(-)`

```
// that is recognized as day month year, not month/day/year
09-05-2016
```

if you can't get the date in a different format you can do a str_replace to remove the slashes

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

here is a [link](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php#100144) that may help you.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `DateTime` class will give you alot more flexibility. For example: Take a look at the `createFromFormat` method which can convert any format of date and time to a valid DateTime Object.

```
// Define your date
$date = '09/05/2016 09:12';

// convert it to a DateTime object
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $date);

// Output - returns 09
echo $date->format('d');
```

For more information take a look at PHP's [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) on DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

set format first your datetime by `date()`. Then call your day!

```
$date = date("d/m/Y h:i",strtotime($date));//format your date as `09/05/2016 09:12`
var_dump(date("d",strtotime($date)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know that your date is not in correct format then re-format it like you want. Just create your date as you want.

> `date_create` will make a new date from your string. `date_format`
>
> will convert your date as a new format Finally a `date` function with
>
> `strtotime` will display your desired result.

```
$str = "09/05/2016 09:12";

$date = date_create($str);
$time = date_format($date, "m-d-Y h:i");

echo date("d", strtotime($time)); //09
```